# ggsave ggpairs plot error

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I save the ggpairs as the current ggsave does not work?

Script:

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1],200),]
pf<-ggpairs(  diamonds.samp[,1:3],mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = cut))
ggsave("C:/Users/top/Desktop/ggpairs.jpg", pf, dpi=500)
```

Comment: You can save with this command, but not the whole plot: `ggsave("C:/Users/top/Desktop/ggpairs.jpg", dpi=500)`

Comment: The issue is that I wish to save all the plot in DPi=500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to use `ggsave` you get an error

```
ggsave("ggpairs.jpg", pf, dpi=500)
```

> Saving 7 x 7 in image
>   Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
>     no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "c('gg', 'ggmatrix')"

So you can write you own `grid.draw` method for the `ggpairs` object class

```
grid.draw.gg <- function(x){
  print(x)
}

ggsave("ggpairs.jpg", pf, dpi=500)
```